# Late evaluation of function argument to formatted_string

Tags: ada

Let's consider this MWE:

```hs
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with GNAT.Strings; use GNAT.Strings;
with GNAT.Command_Line; use GNAT.Command_Line;

procedure  Verbose_And_Image is

   type T_Foo is tagged record
      Member_1 : Natural := 13;
      Member_2 : Float := 1.414;
      Member_3 : Boolean := False;
      Member_4 : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String ("Foo");
      Member_5 : Natural := 42;
   end record;

   function Image (Foo : in T_Foo) return String is
      Message : Unbounded_String :=
         "M1: " & Foo.Member_1'Image & " " &
         "M2: " & Foo.Member_2'Image & " " &
         "M3: " & Foo.Member_3'Image & " " &
         "M4: " & Foo.Member_4 & " " &
         "M5: " & Foo.Member_5'Image;
   begin
      return To_String(Message);
   end Image;

   Global_Foo : T_Foo;
   Config : Command_Line_Configuration;
   Verbose : aliased Boolean := False;
   N_Elem : aliased Integer := 0;

   procedure Debug (Message : in String) is
   begin
      if Verbose then
         Put_Line (Message);
      else
         null;  -- the program is quiet.
      end if;
   end Debug;

   procedure Bar (I : in Integer; Foo : in out T_Foo) is
   begin
      Foo.Member_5  := I;
      Debug ("I is: " & Image (Foo));
   end Bar;


begin
   Define_Switch (Config, Verbose'Access, "-v", Help => "Verbose");
   Define_Switch (Config, N_Elem'Access, "-n:", Help => "Number of tries");
   Getopt (Config);
   Put_Line ("File argument was " & Verbose'Image);

   for I in 1..N_Elem loop

      Bar (I, Global_Foo);

   end loop;

end Verbose_And_Image;
```

Compiling this example with `gnatmake`, we may "profile" our program with:

```
gnatmake -O3 verbose_and_image.adb 
gcc -c -O3 verbose_and_image.adb
gnatbind -x verbose_and_image.ali
gnatlink verbose_and_image.ali -O3
$time ./verbose_and_image  -n 19999999 > /dev/null # In "quiet"

real    0m8.282s
user    0m7.946s
sys 0m0.005s
$time ./verbose_and_image -v -n 19999999 > /dev/null  # In verbose
real    0m19.481s
user    0m11.946s
sys 0m6.756s
```

In many cases, to "optimize" the code, some developers wrote **everywhere**:

```hs
   procedure Bar (I : in Integer; Foo : in out T_Foo) is
   begin
      Foo.Member_5  := I;
      if Verbose then
         Debug ("I is: " & Image (Foo));
      end if;
   end Bar;
```

Which is indeed order of magnitude faster (though my example is not really precise):

```
$time ./verbose_and_image -v -n 19999999 > /dev/null 
real    0m19.585s
user    0m12.146s
sys 0m6.655s
$time ./verbose_and_image  -n 19999999 > /dev/null 
real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.023s
sys 0m0.003s
```

Writing a dedicated `Debug (Message : in String; Foo : in T_Foo)` function leads to comparable performances.

My concern with this later form is that the thousands of `if Level` make the code horribly difficult to read (increasing the cyclomatic complexity) and most of them do not even make sense (no image evaluation inside).
It is also not acceptable to write those dedicated functions each time you want to print a message (plus the debugging is handled by a dedicated package).

Is there a way to offer a procedure based on Formatted_String (for instance) to allow a late evaluation of these Images when needed. Something like:

```hs
procedure Debug(format: in out Formatted_String, ...) is
begin
   if Verbose then
      for argument of arguments loop
         format := format & argument'Image;
      end loop;
      Put_Line (-format);
   end if;
end Debug;
```

So that, at any point, one may do:

```
Debug ( +"Debug %s", Foo);
```

Delaying the evaluation of the images to the `Debug` function and without the need to declare functions any time you want to print some debug message.

Comment: Ada intentionally does not provide a C-like varargs syntax as you suggest in your procedure body for Debug. Note that the variable "argument" is never declared either in the formal parameter list nor as a local variable in Debug. It just magically appears in the loop. If your type Foo is iterable as in http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5-2.html one could iterate through the elements as you suggest, otherwise your approach is doomed.

Comment: @JimRogers Indeed, `arguments` is not declared but is meant by the `...` in the procedure argument. I did consider myself *doomed* at first and would go along with this (a priori evaluating all the `Images`). I'm just trying to see if anyone has an idea on this :)

Comment: And, I might have been rather unclear: I'm looking for an approach that would be independent of the type of the arguments. It is said that Ada 2020 is bringing the ability to perform a `'Image` on any type (if I got this right). My question is not to iterate of the `Foo` type but on a list of ("unknown") arguments as I could do in other programming languages (I know from the beginning that this is not a really Ada-like approach but, on the other side, I know little from the 202x standard :) )

Comment: See also [_Variable-length argument lists_](https://www.adahome.com/articles/1997-06/am_cando_a2.html), discussed [here](https://www.adahome.com/articles/1997-06/am_cando.html#13).

Comment: Is `Level` a compile-time constant? If so, you can use **`separate`** clauses and select a **`null`** `Print_Line` implementation with your build system when `Level = False`, and the compiler can subsequently optimize away calls to `Print_Line`, skipping the evaluation of your string building.

Comment: @trashgod Thankes for the awesome link! I never heard of that possible construct ! However, I see two drawbacks at this implementation: in the two examples, I would need to have knowledge of all the types my developers want to print. And in the second example (which is by far more convenient, I agree), all the types they want to print in debug shall derivate from a single type (right?), which seems rather inconvenient too.

Comment: @flyx this might indeed be the best solution. Though in the current implementation, `Level` is a configuration parameter (equivalent to adding a `--verbose` on the CLI).

Comment: @Vser You could instead have a local `function Debug_Msg return String is ("Debug" & first_foo'Image);` and give a pointer to that function to `Print_Line`.

Comment: Defining a function each time you want to print a debug message and pass an access to it each time you wan't to print a message seems highly unpractical. I've updated my question to make my concern clearer. I'll try to find time today to profile and investigate my question a bit more.

Comment: I rewrote my question around a MWE with performance analyses :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using "formatting strings", if possible.
They're too easy to screw-up and the compiler generally can't confirm that you're not making some mistake the way it can with `Text_IO.Put_Line( "First-part " & Image(Object) & " second part.")` or `Text_IO.Put("First-part ")`/`Enumeration_IO.put(Object)`/`Text_IO.Put_Line(" second part.")`.

The way to handle the need for variable length inputs is typically via unconstrained arrays or Ada containers (esp vectors).